# Standard size of symbols in equation

Tags: symbols, fontsize, size

Is there some kind of standard symbol size in LaTeX? I am looking to design an icon in the Latex font based on how certain operations or symbols look like in latex. For example the square operation with a "placeholder" (that should be the standard symbol size of latex) as the base and 2 as the exponent.

I know that sizes in Latex are dynamic most of the time but I was still wondering if there maybe is something like this.

I appreciate every answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a `\basesymbol` (placeholder) of some arbitrary size, `\scalerel` can be used to scale it to a standard size, as long as you define what "standard" is.  Here, in the first example, `\scaledsymbol` takes the base symbol and always makes it the height of `x`, in the current math style.  In the 2nd example, it mimics the size of the `+` sign, and takes on `\mathbin` characteristics.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel} 
\newcommand\basesymbol{\begingroup\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\relax
  \fboxrule=1pt\relax\fbox{\rule{5pt}{5pt}\raisebox{5pt}{\rule{5pt}{5pt}}}%
  \endgroup}
\newcommand\scaledsymbol{\scalerel*{\basesymbol}{x}}
\begin{document}
Base: A\basesymbol B

Scaled to $x$: $y = \scaledsymbol^2 + x_{\scaledsymbol}$

\renewcommand\scaledsymbol{\mathbin{\scalerel*{\basesymbol}{+}}}

Scaled to $+$: $y = x^2 \scaledsymbol x_{i \scaledsymbol 1}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful! Thanks!